# Issue in setting function app proxies for base url

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

I want to set the base url of the azure function app to point to the static html page hosted in different domain.

After setting the proxy (Route template to "**/**"  and  Backend URL to "**new url**") in Azure function app, base ulr doesn't get redirected to the new URL.

Answer (score 0):

I see this too. It's a bug, is fixed (see https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/commit/7728897797040879d88c3a3ddddbfb63fbac4a6d ). The fix will be deployed in the next  release, which usually comes every few weeks.